# I need to get the data for first 5 days and 6-10 days using created date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

As in the heading, I need to get the data for first 5 days,6-10 days.
I have 3 parameters:start date,end date,user

I have data for create date as below

```
Createdate
----------------

2019-11-01
2019-11-04
2019-11-05
2019-11-10
2019-11-21
2019-11-30
```

So as you see above we have 3 dates under first 5 days and 1 date under 6-10 days.

I used below query

```
Select count(date) 
from   Data
Where  cast(cdate as date) between cast(cdate as date)  
                               and dateadd(day,5,cdate) Group by cdate

Expected results
-------------
Date         First 5   6-10 
----         -----     ----
2019-11-01     1
2019-11-04     1
2019-11-05     1
2019-11-10     0        1
```

But I'm getting all the data instead of only 3 days in first 5 days.
Please any one help

Comment: please provide your query currently you are using.

Comment: please show us the expected result

Comment: Give us your sample data and expected results.

Comment: The actual results already provided and expected results will update

Answer (score 0):

Try this below logic with DATEADD method-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da46e9bbbbbcdff9737aeb661c2fb87b)

```
Select cdate 
from   Data
Where  cdate >= DATEADD(DD,-5,GETDATE())
```

New Query:

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be3a05d2f1e2d95b2fd8076be119d021)

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE cdate >=
(
    SELECT MIN(cdate) 
    FROM (
        select DISTINCT TOP 5  cdate 
        from data 
        order by cdate DESC
    )A 
)
```

Comment: It's resulting me into last 5 days but I want the dates with next 5 days using cdate

Comment: @VasZ Pelase check the new query logic. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the next statement may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    CreateDate date
)
INSERT INTO Data 
    (CreateDate)
VALUES
    ('20191101'),
    ('20191104'),
    ('20191105'),
    ('20191110'),
    ('20191121'),
    ('20191130')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
    CreateDate,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  = 0 THEN 1 END AS [First 5 Days], 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  = 1 THEN 1 END AS [6-10 Days], 
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  > 1 THEN 1 END AS [More Days] 
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
CreateDate  First 5 Days    6-10 Days   More Days
2019-11-01  1               NULL        NULL
2019-11-04  1               NULL        NULL
2019-11-05  1               NULL        NULL
2019-11-10  NULL            1           NULL
2019-11-21  NULL            NULL        1
2019-11-30  NULL            NULL        1
```

If you have rows with duplicate dates, use the next statement:

```
SELECT
    CreateDate,
    SUM([First 5 Days]) AS [First 5 Days],
    SUM([6-10 Days]) AS [6-10 Days],
    SUM([More Days]) AS [More Days]
FROM (
    SELECT
        CreateDate,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  = 0 THEN 1 END AS [First 5 Days], 
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  = 1 THEN 1 END AS [6-10 Days], 
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate ASC), CreateDate) / 5  > 1 THEN 1 END AS [More Days] 
    FROM Data 
) t
GROUP BY CreateDate
```